# spacy showing import module error while it is already installed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spacy

spacy is installed in vir env in python console

> Building wheels for collected packages: en-core-web-sm   Building
>   wheel for en-core-web-sm (setup.py) ... done   Created wheel for
>   en-core-web-sm: filename=en_core_web_sm-2.1.0-cp36-none-any.whl
>   size=11074439
>   sha256=f67b5d1a325b5d49f50c2a0765610c51d01ff2644e78fa8568fc141506dac87c
>   Stored in directory:
>   C:\Users\DUDE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-02mgn7_m\wheels\39\ea\3b\507f7df78be8631a7a3d7090962194cf55bc1158572c0be77f
>   Successfully built en-core-web-sm Installing collected packages:
>   en-core-web-sm Successfully installed en-core-web-sm-2.1.0 ✔ Download
>   and installation successful You can now load the model via
>   spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') You do not have sufficient privilege to
>   perform this operation. ✘ Couldn't link model to 'en' Creating a
>   symlink in spacy/data failed. Make sure you have the required
>   permissions and try re-running the command as admin, or use a
>   virtualenv. You can still import the model as a module and call its
>   load() method, or create the symlink manually.
>   E:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm -->
>   E:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en ⚠ Download
>   successful but linking failed Creating a shortcut link for 'en' didn't
>   work (maybe you don't have admin permissions?), but you can still load
>   the model via its full package name: nlp =
>   spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

Tried this in jupyter notebook

!pip install spacy

> Requirement already satisfied: spacy in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (2.1.8) Requirement
>   already satisfied: blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.2 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (0.2.4)
>   Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (2.22.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (1.0.2)
>   Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.2.0 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (0.2.2)
>   Requirement already satisfied: srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (0.1.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (1.17.1)
>   Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (0.9.6)
>   Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (2.0.2)
>   Requirement already satisfied: preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (2.0.1)
>   Requirement already satisfied: thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from spacy) (7.0.8)
>   Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from
>   requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2019.6.16) Requirement already
>   satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from
>   requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (1.25.3) Requirement already
>   satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in
>   e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from
>   requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (3.0.4) Requirement already satisfied:
>   idna<2.9,>=2.5 in e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages (from
>   requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2.8) Requirement already satisfied:
>   tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 in e:\anaconda\envs\textmining\lib\site-packages
>   (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8->spacy) (4.35.0)

```
import spacy
tok=spacy.load("en")

doc=tok(test_sentence)
[x.text for x in doc]
```

> Getting error ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback
>   (most recent call last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import spacy
>         2 tok=spacy.load("en")
>         3 
>         4 doc=tok(test_sentence)
>         5 [x.text for x in doc]
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run the spacy in python console, so I assumed the problem was with jupyter notebook. I followed https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/

what i did is, I added **pip install ipykernel**
then
**ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname**
At this point, you can start jupyter, create a new notebook and select the kernel that lives inside your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I use windows, but its same for other OS. You should check your administrative rights and privilege. For Windows visit the User Account > Change User Account Control Settings > Pull down the bar to never notify. Try re running the install prompt. Should be fine.